# Can't run php bin/magento

Tags: magento2, php, cache, cli, command-line

Trying to set up a site from production (new to Magento and doing some fixes) and getting this error when running `php bin/magento`

> We're sorry, an error occurred. Try clearing the cache and code
>   generation directories. By default, they are: var/cache, var/di,
>   var/generation, and var/page_cache.
>
> [Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException] No such entity.

From my troubleshooting so far, I have gathered that the error is being thrown because the website ID is not set or associated.

```
Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException: 
No such entity. in /htdocs/vendor/magento/module-
store/Model/WebsiteRepository.php:104 

Stack trace: 
0: /htdocs/var/generation/Magento/Store/Model/WebsiteRepository/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteRepository->getById('1')

1: /htdocs/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManager.php(201): Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteRepository\Interceptor->getById('1') 

2: /htdocs/var/generation/Magento/Store/Model/StoreManager/Interceptor.php(102): Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager->getWebsite('1') 

3: /htdocs/var/generation/Magento/Store/Model/StoreManagerInterface/Proxy.php(135): Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager\Interceptor->getWebsite('1') 

4: /htdocs/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Resolver/Website.php(30): Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface\Proxy->getWebsite('1') 

5: /htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ScopeCodeResolver.php(49): Magento\Store\Model\Resolver\Website->getScope('1') 

6: /htdocs/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Source/RuntimeConfigSource.php(82): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeCodeResolver->resolve('websites', '1') 

7: /htdocs/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Source/RuntimeConfigSource.php(58): Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->loadConfig() 

8: /htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ConfigSourceAggregated.php(40): Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->get('') 

9: /htdocs/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated->get() 

10: /htdocs/var/generation/Magento/Config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader->read() 

11: /htdocs/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(212): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader\Proxy->read() 

12: /htdocs/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(170): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->loadDefaultScopeData('default') 

13: /htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(139): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->get('default/web/sec...') 

14: /htdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Config/Interceptor.php(63): Magento\Framework\App\Config->get('system', 'default/web/sec...', NULL) 

15: /htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(90): Magento\Framework\App\Config\Interceptor->get('system', 'default/web/sec...') 

16: /htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('web/secure/use_...', 'default', NULL) 

17: /htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\Config\Interceptor->___callParent('getValue', Array) 

18: /htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'getValue', Object(Magento\Framework\App\Config\Interceptor), Array, 'mageworx_shippi...') 

19: /htdocs/app/code/MageWorx/ShippingRules/Model/Plugin/AddMethods.php(54): Magento\Framework\App\Config\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('web/secure/use_...', 'default', NULL) 

20: /htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): MageWorx\ShippingRules\Model\Plugin\AddMethods->aroundGetValue(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Config\Interceptor), Object(Closure), 'web/secure/use_...', 'default', NULL) 

21: /htdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Config/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\Config\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getValue', Array, Array) 

22: /htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(103): Magento\Framework\App\Config\Interceptor->getValue('web/secure/use_...', 'default', NULL) 


23: /htdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Config/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Config->isSetFlag('web/secure/use_...', 'default', NULL) 

24: /htdocs/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/HeaderProvider/Hsts.php(48): Magento\Framework\App\Config\Interceptor->isSetFlag('web/secure/use_...') 

25: /htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Response/HeaderManager.php(41): Magento\Store\Model\HeaderProvider\Hsts->canApply() 

26: /htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(123): Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderManager->beforeSendResponse(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor)) 

27: /htdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php(117): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendResponse', Array, Array) 

28: /htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(185): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendResponse() 

29: /htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(156):Magento\Framework\App\Http->handleDeveloperMode(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException)) 

30: /htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263): Magento\Framework\App\Http->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException)) 

31: /htdocs/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http)) 

32: {main}
```

Comment: remove all this directory `var/cache`, `var/di`, `var/generation`, and `var/page_cache` and then try again.

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands below, the key is removing the **var/*** folders.

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"    
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
chmod +x bin/magento
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/di/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;
mage setup:upgrade 
mage cache:flush 
mage setup:static-content:deploy -j 10
mage setup:di:compile
mage deploy:mode:set production -s
mage maintenance:disable
```